# MongoDB find join array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with data that looks sort of like this

```json
{
  "part": [
    { "a": "1", "b": "a" },
    { "a": "23", "b": "b" },
    { "a": "4", "b": "c" },
  ]
}
```

What I would like is a way of searching for documents where the join of all `a` parts equals the search that I am looking for.

for example `1234` should match the document above, but `124` should not.

is this possible with MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Aggregation framework:

- **$match** with **$eq** - To filter only documents where concatenated `a`  properties of `part` array are equal to the input string.
- **$reduce** with **$concat** - To concatenate all `a` properties of `part` array for each document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          "1234",
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$part",
              "initialValue": "",
              "in": {
                "$concat": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.a"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hYDVX1UcykW)

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate with `$reduce` to join string then `$match` to filter your string.
Here is the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AKd2AtPp-_6).